# ReactDOM.render not rendering changes

Tags: reactjs

so I have this, which is rendering on a page "react render"

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const root = document.getElementById('root');
  ReactDOM.render(<h1>react render</h1>, root);
});
```

I've changed `<h1>react render</h1>` to `<h1>changed</h1>` and it is still showing "react render" on localhost after a refresh.

Comment: The information in the question is not enough to help you, sadly. What does your project setup look like?

Comment: Sorry about that, what setup are you talking about? It's rails app with react.js and Basically grabbed element from rail's view from react, which is the file up there.

Comment: looks like you might be running production build version of the site, and you need to rebuild it to see changes, 
if you would run it in development version then changes would be reflected even without reload

take a look at create react app https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app and start playing with it and you will see how it automatically reloads changes

Comment: okay I was able to fix it re running 'npm install', but is there a better way of doing this? I wouldn't want to 'npm install' everytime I make changes to this project.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it has to do something with webpack super lost